# A confusion i have about HTML "classes"

Tags: html, css, class

Hello and thanks in advance. In HTML I know that a "class" will not really have an effect unless it is related to something in CSS or JS. At the same time, I find some "classes" that do affect the structure of a documents even without an associated CSS, such as "class="col-md-12" for example. Can someone explain why some classes work independent of CSS? And how to know them.

Comment: class="col-md-12" is a bootstrap class, and have its own CSS file.

Comment: Like @FelippeDuarte said, it's defined in bootstrap.

Comment: You are incorrect. You must be linking to Bootstrap CSS files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The idea of classes ("class=''") and identifiers ("id=''") is part of DOM manipulation.  You can put in classes and id's in each of the tags as you desire.  Normally, the rule is an independent id for each tag, and a class for each GROUP of identical tags.

To make use of classes, you are required to use CSS, be it at the top of the page, or linked to another page.  If you have your CSS at the top of the page, you do not need another CSS page, however most designers will frown from that.

See here for a more in-depth explanation: https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 0):

`class="col-md-12"` still requires CSS. That is a common class for a framework such as [BootStrap](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/). On its own without JavaScript or CSS, a class does nothing besides tell another programmer what an element is for.